# Flexslider issue - large blue flash appearing seconds after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider, flexslider

I've been having some issues with a flexslider on a Wordpress-built site. Basically, when the page loads and the sldier loads a large blue flash appears for a split second then disappears. You can see it in the link below:

http://www.jacksonvilletreebarbers.com/

I'm guessing the jquery isn't called correctly, or at the right time. But I could be wrong.

And help or input would be a great help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> If you initiate FlexSlider with the fade animation after page load when images are visible, FlexSlider will set the opacity on the first image to 0 and then fade it in. This will cause a "flashing" which is quite ugly.

One possible solution which doesn't involve any javascript hacking.

> 1. Add a `.loading` class on your flexslider container, e.g. `<div class="flexslider loading">`.
> 2. Configure your flex init script by adding:

```
start: function(slider) { slider.removeClass('loading');  }
```

> 3. Add this to your CSS:

```
.flexslider.loading .slides > li:first-child { opacity: 1 !important; }
```

More about this problem: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/848

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, it didn't do the trick. I'll keep looking into it and post whatever I can find.